# Zones 2 and 3 are red on the board and little air flow going upstairs

Tags: electrical

My upstairs is not cooling. I changed out the blower motor and my zone 2 and 3 lights are red on the board. I checked the dampers and both were closed. What are my next steps?

Comment: Nobody knows what a red light means without knowing the make and model of the equipment involved. Please [edit] your post to include that. It might also help to include a general drawing of your house, HVAC system and indicate where the zones are. We don't know if it's zone 1, 2, or 3 or some combination that cools your upstairs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Was there a reason you changed the blower motor?  It sounds like you have an active control system. We would need to know the brand and model of the control board and the type of temp monitor in each zone (thermistors) can go bad, manually opening the dampers unless they are smoke/fire can get air flow until it can be figured out. Smoke/fire dampers are designed to fail closed (spring wound so loss of power or control they close) also the electronics that control the motor inside a smoke/fire damper if that fails they close.